# Filling panel with circular bar plot chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm studying some chunks of code found on the web for printing circular bar plot charts. I'm not able to "zoom" or reduce white space in order to have a bigger chart. I attach a pic, I'd like to reduce the area at least over and below the chart (in the area colored in red). Any hint please?

Chart with target area for "manipulation" in red:

[image]

p.s. sorry for the messy code, just experimenting...

```
source("code_wrang_eda_danger.R")
medie <- round(rowMeans(df_danger_Totals[, 2:12]), digits = 3)
tab1 <- cbind(df_danger_Totals,medie)
tab2 <-tibble::rowid_to_column(tab1, "id")
tab3 <- tab2 %>% 
        select(id, cer, medie) 

label_data <- tab3
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <-  90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar    
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

p <- ggplot(tab3, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=medie)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=alpha("skyblue", 0.7)) +
        
        # Limits of the plot = very important. The negative value controls the size of the inner circle, the positive one is useful to add size over each bar
        ylim(-380,450) +
        
        # Custom the theme: no axis title and no cartesian grid
        #theme_minimal() +
        theme(
                axis.text = element_blank(),
                axis.title = element_blank(),
                panel.grid = element_blank(),
                #plot.margin = margin(0.5, 0.50, 0.5, 0.5, "cm"),
                plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = "red",
                                                colour = "red"),
                axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                panel.spacing.x = unit(0.5, "lines"),
                panel.spacing.y = unit(0.5, "lines"), 
                plot.margin = margin(t = 5,  # Top margin
                                     r = 5,  # Right margin
                                     b = 5,  # Bottom margin
                                     l = 5) # Left margin
        ) +
        
        # This makes the coordinate polar instead of cartesian.
        coord_polar(start = 0) +
        
        # Add the labels, using the label_data dataframe that we have created before
        geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=medie+10, label=cer, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) 


p <- p + labs(title = "xxx",
              subtitle = "xxx",
              caption = "xxx") +
        theme(
                plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14),    # Center title position and size
                plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),            # Center subtitle
                plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "italic")# move caption to the left
        ) 

ggsave(path = "charts","pog_waste_coll_2008_2018_danger_circ_barplot.png", width = 5, height = 5)

p
```

Comment: OP, this is due to the way in which the data is transposed to a polar coordinate system.  If you turn on axis labels at the top of the y axis, this becomes more apparent (or turn on gridlines).  The shape of the plot is going to be a circle, so the plot area is a square containing that circle.  The radius of the circle is determined by the max height of your bars, so the one to the right that is higher than the others forces the whole shape of the plot.  The best you could do here is either crop the output picture or use rect grobs to cover the plot (but the image is still the same size.

Comment: Uh, it is clear... Thank you very much!